# Builder pattern with Reactor mono

Tags: java, design-patterns, reactor

I have a rocket class. I want to instantiate a rocket object via builder. I need to get some state from database via reactive repository, but reactive repository returns either Mono or Flux. How do I properly inject state to the builder with Mono and Flux. Here's what I have tried.

```
public class Rocket {

  private String engine;
  private String fuel;

  public Rocket(Builder builder) {
    engine = builder.getEngine();
    fuel = builder.getFuel();
  }

  public static class Builder {

    private String engine;
    protected Mono<String> engineCollector;

    private String fuel;
    protected Mono<String> fuelCollector;

    public Builder() {
    }

    protected Builder setEngine(Mono<String> engineCollector) {
      this.engineCollector = engineCollector.doOnNext((collect) -> {
        this.engine = collect;
      });
      return this;
    }

    private Builder setFuel(Mono<String> fuelCollector) {
      this.fuelCollector = fuelCollector.doOnNext((collect) -> {
        this.engine = collect;
      });
      return this;
    }

    public String getEngine() {
      return this.engine;
    }

    public String getFuel() {
      return this.fuel;
    }

    public Rocket build() {
      return engineCollector
        .flatMap(s -> fuelCollector)
        .then(Mono.just(new Rocket(this)))
        .block();
    }
  }
}
```

Is this approach good or bad what's the proper way

Comment: `Mono` is not a value - it's a promise of a value some time in the future. You can't directly covnert `Mono<String>` to anything that you need *right now* - but you could convert `Mono<String>` into `Mono<Rocket>` that would resolve some time in the future, when `Mono<String>` is resolved.

Comment: Yes, just wanted to suggest the same: instead of using reactive types in the builder, do the opposite: use builder in the reactive operators. Then you got a `Mono<Rocket>` in the end when you subscribe.

Answer (score 2):

One way to combine builder with reactive API is the following

```
Mono.just(Rocket.builder())
        .flatMap(builder ->
                engineCollector()
                        .map(builder::engine)
                        .thenReturn(builder)
        )
        .flatMap(builder ->
                fuelCollector()
                        .map(builder::fuel)
                        .thenReturn(builder)
        )
        .map(builder -> builder.build());
```

where

```
@Builder
class Rocket {
    private String engine;
    private String fuel;
}

Mono<String> engineCollector() {
...
}
    
Mono<String> fuelCollector() {
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know we could made builder pattern with @Builder this is cool!

Answer (score 2):

As I said, in the comment, trying to convert `Mono` into something that is is not a reactive type kind of flies in the face of using reactive programming to begin with.

According to reactive paradigm, you shouldn't try to create `Rocket` when you have `Mono<Engine>` and `Mono<FuelTank>`. You should be creating a `Mono<Rocket>`, instead.

Now, the code (note, that I would use the actual nominal types instead of just strings, for readability purposes). I personally would prefer the [Mono::zip](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zip-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-java.util.function.BiFunction-) operation for most of cases you describe. For the case of just two values, you would not even need the builder:

```
public class Rocket {
    ....
    public Rocket(Engine engine, FuelTank fuel) {
        ....
    }
    ....
}

Mono<Engine> engine = repo.getRocketEngine();
Mono<FuelTank> tank = repo.getRocketFuelTank();

Mono<Rocket> rocket = Mono.zip(engine, tank, Rocket::new);
```

When you do have more than two properties, this becomes a little more involved, but still pretty straigntforward. For example, consider that your rocket has three parts: `NoseCone`, `Engine`, and `FuelTank`, instead of two. Well, the `Mono::zip` [has us covered](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zip-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-) with overrides that produce tuples, having arity of [up to eight](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zip-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-):

```
Mono<NoseCone> cone = repo.getRocketNoseCone();
Mono<Engine> engine = repo.getRocketEngine();
Mono<FuelTank> tank = repo.getRocketFuelTank();

Mono<Tuple3<NoseCone, Engine, FuelTank>> builderStage1 = Mono.zip(cone, engine, tank);

Mono<Rocket> rocket = builderStage1.map(tuple -> {
    NoseCone coneValue = tuple.getT1();
    Engine engineValue = tuple.getT2();
    FuelTank tankValue = tuple.getT3();

    return Rocket.builder()
        .engine(engineValue)
        .fuel(tankValue)
        .noseCone(coneValue)
        .build();
});
```

Or, to shorten the last few lines of code a little bit and get rid of ugly long type signatures:

```
Mono<Rocket> rocket = Mono.zip(cone, engine, tank).map(tuple -> Rocket.builder()
    .noseCone(tuple.getT1())
    .engine(tuple.getT2())
    .fuel(tuple.getT3))
    .build()
);
```