# WebFlux & synchronous call

Tags: asynchronous, spring-webflux

I have an application written with WebFlux. It hasn't issues, everything works great.

Right now I need to integrate with an old third party system that doesn't have WebFlux support.

I have included the dependency and have interface with the following method

```
ResultDto sendResponse(String id){}

...

return ResultDto.builder
.info1() <- set Mono<Info1>
.info2() <- set Mono<Info2>
.info3() <- set Mono<Info3>
...
.build()
```

How to correctly form **ResultDto** in my case? Use block ?
But this is the wrong approach in reactive applications.

Comment: To be clear, you want to implement the `ResultDto sendResponse(String id)` method, and internally, you use Reactor. That's it ? Is it possible to return a `Future<ResultDto>` instead ? If not, then, yes zipping all your monos then blocking on the result is the only way I know. If you're outside a Netty/Reactor context, this is not a big problem.

Comment: The only way to get result in a sync way is to block reactive flow at some point.  For example you can apply builder pattern https://stackoverflow.com/a/71522893/9068895 and then block but ion case this is the only non-reactive part in the app I would rather wrap this component and run in a separate scheduler https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#faq.wrap-blocking